# FFmpeg removed video rotation information

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, rotation, metadata

Currently I'm using FFmpeg to edit and compress video. But when I edit the video, it removed my metadata which is the video rotational information.

```
    String cmd = "-ss" +"command" + " ";
```

The video is not rotated but the rotation information is removed and causes the video output to be changed.

How do I maintain the video rotation information and also the video rotation?

Initially the matrix was Rotate 90 but the converted video is:

```
Matrix{u=0.0, v=0.0, w=1.0, a=0.0, b=1.0, c=-1.0, d=0.0, tx=360.0, ty=0.0}
```

The video conversion changed the rotation Matrix.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-noautorotate` as a switch.

Comment: How should I implement -noautorotate? I tried:
cmd = cmd + "-noautorotate"; but it produces error. Please advice.

Comment: Initially the matrix was Rotate 90 but the converted video is:

    Matrix{u=0.0, v=0.0, w=1.0, a=0.0, b=1.0, c=-1.0, d=0.0, tx=360.0, ty=0.0}

The video conversion changed the rotation Matrix.

Any advice on how to implement -noautorotate? Thank you.

Comment: @MeiYi What is the error? You should always provide the actual error instead of only mentioning that there is an error. My guess is that your `ffmpeg` is old, but you never provided any `ffmpeg` output, so it remains a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add try the line `cmd = cmd + "-vf transpose=0";`